# How to combine every 3 lines from a read document in python

Tags: python, iteration

I am reading from a document with output as follows:

```
Pretzel Crisps Original/Thin/Crunchy Pretzel Crackers Pretzels, 7.2 oz

1 × $2.14

$2.14

Bagel Bites Cheese & Pepperoni Mini Bagels, 40 count, 31.1 oz

1 × $7.98

$7.98

SuperPretzel Cheddar Cheese Filled Soft Pretzel Sticks Softstix, 9 Oz

1 × $2.56

$2.56
```

I would like to combine every 3 lines on a new line as follows:

```
Pretzel Crisps Original/Thin/Crunchy Pretzel Crackers Pretzels 7.2 oz, 1 × $2.14, $2.14

Bagel Bites Cheese & Pepperoni Mini Bagels 40 count 31.1 oz, 1 × $7.98, $7.98

SuperPretzel Cheddar Cheese Filled Soft Pretzel Sticks Softstix 9 Oz, 1 × $2.56, $2.56
```

I have tried the following code:

```
product=[]
quantity=[]
price=[]
count=1

with open('test.txt','r')as document:  
    for line in document:
        line=line.replace('\n','')
        if count == 1:
            line=line.replace(',','')
            product.append(line)
        if count == 2:
            quantity.append(line)
        if count == 3:
            price.append(line)
        count+=1
    all=list(zip(product,quantity,price))
    print(all)
```

This code will only return the first three lines of the document as desired.  I've tried other solutions on this site but they all combine the entire document into one long string.

Comment: Seems quite similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45774259/python-how-to-extract-specific-string-into-multiple-variable/45775212#45775212

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
data = [i.strip('\n') for i in open('filename.txt')]

new_data = [' ,'.join(data[i:i+3]) for i in range(0, len(data), 3)]

f = open('filename.txt', 'w')
for i in new_data:
   f.write("{}\n".format(i))

f.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a perfect match for this kind of task in the [`itertools` recipe documentation](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes): `grouper`

```
from itertools import zip_longest
# in case you use python 2 use "from itertools import izip_longest as zip_longest

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
```

Then you could use:

```
with open('test.txt','r') as document:
    res = [', '.join(group) for group in grouper(map(str.strip, document), 3)]
```

Just to illustrate how it roughly works I included the string as list of lines:

```
astring = """Pretzel Crisps Original/Thin/Crunchy Pretzel Crackers Pretzels, 7.2 oz
1 × $2.14
$2.14
Bagel Bites Cheese & Pepperoni Mini Bagels, 40 count, 31.1 oz
1 × $7.98
$7.98
SuperPretzel Cheddar Cheese Filled Soft Pretzel Sticks Softstix, 9 Oz
1 × $2.56
$2.56""".split('\n')

[','.join(group) for group in grouper(astring, 3)]
#['Pretzel Crisps Original/Thin/Crunchy Pretzel Crackers Pretzels, 7.2 oz,1 × $2.14,$2.14',
# 'Bagel Bites Cheese & Pepperoni Mini Bagels, 40 count, 31.1 oz,1 × $7.98,$7.98',
# 'SuperPretzel Cheddar Cheese Filled Soft Pretzel Sticks Softstix, 9 Oz,1 × $2.56,$2.56']
```